# Error trying to implement a tick with register_tick_function

Tags: php, php-7.1

I tried implementing this tick method in a Win 8 WAMP server running PHP 7.1

```
<?php
declare(ticks=1);

function tick()
{
    echo "tick_handler() called\n";
}

register_tick_function('tick');

if (1 > 0) {
    print(1);
}
```

But I end up with this error after a process that seem more like an infinite loop:

> The connection was reset

Mean while the code works on a live sever running PHP 7.1 and also on a WIN 8 WAMP server running PHP 5.5

Comment: Why have you declared tick(s) instead of tick at the start?

Comment: @SwitchCase http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks